# JSON String not parsing correctly PHP

Tags: php

I get the following output from an API call:

```
$json = file_get_contents($service_url);
```

the var_dump of $json gives me:

```
string(308) " [{"Transaction_ID":2805579},{"Transaction_ID":2777876},{"Transaction_ID":2808406}]"
```

However,
var_dump(json_decode($json)) returns a null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should't you use json_decode instead of decode_json?

Comment: sorry that was a typo. I am using json_decode

Comment: "NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit. " http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

decode_json isn't a function, you should use json_decode

```
var_dump(json_decode($json))
```